# Can't get :hover or any pseudo-classes to work in react + material UI

Tags: reactjs, pseudo-class, es6-class, mui, jss

I've gotten all other styling objects to work but for some reason pseudo-classes don't seem to render or they throw an error I'm using the jss-preset-default settings. Below the jssTest component is a commented sample of the different  combinations I've tried, along with how they rendered when I inspected them.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const styles = theme => ({
    root: {
        color: "#ff0000",
        "&:hover": {
            color: "#0000ff"
        }
    }
});

class JssTest extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1 style={styles("").root}>JSS Test</h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

//<h1 classes={styles("").root}>JSS Test</h1>
//Styles nothing and Renders as
//<h1 classes="[object Object]">JSS Test</h1>

//<h1 style={styles("").root}>JSS Test</h1>
//Renders just the color but not the '&:hover'
//<h1 style="color: rgb(255, 0, 0);">JSS Test</h1>

//<h1 classes={classes.root}>JSS Test</h1>
//get   Line 18:  'classes' is not defined  no-undef

//<h1 classes={styles.root}>JSS Test</h1>
//renders as
//<h1>JSS Test</h1>

export default withStyles(styles)(JssTest);
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of `<h1 style={styles("").root}>JSS Test</h1>`
use `<h1 className={this.props.classes.root}>JSS Test</h1>`

Comment: Awesome thank you, Just figured out it's creating its own class and this.props.classes.root maps to it, I'd up vote you but SO's not letting me

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out set className to this.props.classes.root 
Hopefully this saves someone else from wasting a day

```
<h1 className={this.props.classes.root}>JSS Test</h1>
```